# Keyup only works with remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner at jQuery. I am facing a strange problem. I have the following js which is not working

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#widget_search_affiliate_product").keyup(function() {
        console.log("hey");
    });
});
```

But the strange thing is when I add

```
$("#widget_search_affiliate_product").remove();
```

above the keyup function, the keyup function starts working. So this code does output "hey" in the console when I type something in the widget_search_affiliate_product search field

```js
(function( $ ) {
 'use strict';

 $( document ).ready(function() {

   /* Ajax Widget Search */

   $("#widget_search_affiliate_product").remove();
   

   $("#widget_search_affiliate_product").keyup(function() {
    console.log("hey");
   });
  });

    })( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```js
(function( $ ) {
 'use strict';

 $( document ).ready(function() {

   /* Ajax Widget Search */

   console.log($('[id=widget_search_affiliate_product]').length);  
   $("#widget_search_affiliate_product").keyup(function() {
    console.log("hey");
   });
  });




})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="alp_search_product">
     <p>
      <label for="affiliate_product_single"><strong>Search Affiliate Product:</strong></label><br>
      
        <input class="widefat" type="text" name="widget_search_affiliate_product" id="widget_search_affiliate_product">
     </p>
        <div class="hidden" id="suggesstion_box">
       <ul></ul>
       <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
      </div>
      
        <input id="affiliate_product_single" name="affiliate_product_single" type="hidden" value="Search Affiliate Product">
      <input type="hidden" id="widget_ajax_nonce" name="" value="6286139014">


<div class="alp_select_product">
      <h5 class="heading_selected_product">Selected Product</h5>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps in your `/* Ajax Widget Search */` part - you had missed a *semicolon* ?

Comment: Sounds like you are using duplicate IDs. IDs must be unique on document context. Check it by using before keyup binding and without remove element: `console.log($('[id=widget_search_affiliate_product]').length);`. If anything above 1, you get your answer

Comment: @gurvinder372 I've pasted the whole js and checked there are no missing columns or brackets

Comment: @A.Wolff I've pasted the html and checked through your code too it returns 1

Comment: There's something else going on, your code works as it should https://jsfiddle.net/en1sovt2/

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yes it works in my fiddle too, Strange. let me dig in more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I had two instances of `widget_search_affiliate_product`. The following solved the issue

```
(function( $ ) {
'use strict';

$( document ).ready(function() {

    /* Ajax Widget Search */

    $("#widget_search_affiliate_product").remove();


    $(".alp_widget #widget_search_affiliate_product").keyup(function() {
        console.log("hey");
    });
});

})( jQuery );
```